# Vuejs [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'smAndDown' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

After install vuetify into my webpack.config.js i have this message in console. And view is not render correctly.

```
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'smAndDown' of undefined"

found in

---> <VToolbar>
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
   new CopyWebpackPlugin([
       {
           from: path.join(__dirname, './assets'),
           to: path.join(__dirname, 'public/assets')
       }
   ]),
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       env: JSON.stringify(env)
   }),
   new VueLoaderPlugin(),
   new VuetifyLoaderPlugin(),
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       hash: true,
       template: "./src/index.html"
   })
]);
```

*babel*

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
    ]
}
```

Whats i missing? thanks